# Can a Macbook 4,1 use 64bit architecture?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

I have a Macbook 4,1 running Mac OS X 10.7, and I need to install the [MESA program](http://mesa.sourceforge.net), that only works on 64bit machines. Running `uname` tells me that my mac is working in 32bit mode, and a quick search online told me that it should be able to run as 64bit, which is what I need.

```
$: uname -m
i386
```

Following [Apple's advice](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht3773), I tried to get my computer to boot up again in 64bit mode, and verified it with `uname` again, to discover I'd failed. So, my question is, **can my macbook work in 64bit mode?**

Comment: I think the general rule of thumb is that if it can't run OS X 10.8 it can't do 64-bit kernel - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT3770

Comment: From [another page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201948), I get that I have a 64bit processor, but not a 64bit kernel. According to [this answer on Superuser](http://superuser.com/a/340644), the issue may be 32bit drivers preventing me from using a 64bit kernel.

Comment: As a general rule if you can not run OS X 10.6 with a 64bit kernel then you are out of luck. The MacBook EFI prevents running the 64 bit kernel. If I'm not mistaken the last OS X upgrade for a MacBook is 10.7  with running a 32 bit kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply have software that needs to run as 64bit then yes it is compatible, if you have software that needs a 64bit kernel (rare) then no it is not compatible. From looking at the website where it shows system requirements it shows it needs a 64bit capable CPU, which is what your MacBook has, same CPU as my iMac. As you can see below on my Late 2006 iMac with 2GHz Core 2 Duo running 10.7.5 with a 32bit kernel and all 64bit processes. [image]